# Performance difference between accesing properties with getters vs assigning it to variable and then accesing it

Tags: java, performance, variables, memory

Is there any performance difference (or memory usage difference at least) in Java when I access class property trough getter vs. when I assign value from getter into new variable and then access it?

This is simple example:

```java
class Foo {
    String bar = "bar";

    public String getBar() {
        return property;
    }
}


Foo foo = new Foo();

// Accessing value directly
System.out.println(foo.getBar());

// Accessing it trough "middleman" variable
String bar = foo.getBar();
System.out.println(bar);
```

I suppose that until Java compiler see that I am not changing value of `bar`, it will ignore the variable and generates the code in a way that it will be same as first example? Or I am wrong?

Comment: `bar` is simply a variable that holds the reference to the return of `foo.getBar()`.  Assigning a new variable for an already existing reference is not expensive, unless you are doing that 1000s of times and/or holding these references in an unwanted manner (that they don't get garbage collected and cause memory leak).  Otherwise, there would be literally no performance difference between the two approaches for any practical purposes.  You might want to do that and check the readings with a profiler.  You will only start noticing a difference if you do that in a loop for 1000s of times.

Comment: That makes no different because the compiler does a lot of optimizations. If ```bar``` is not used in the further code, no extra memory will be allocated.